# can apache be configured to create separate sets of processes listening on different IPs for security?

Tags: configuration, apache2

I am trying to check if the following is possible.

I have a single apache config file that listens on port 80 for external traffic and port 8080 for internal traffic.
Can I configure in such a way that there are (say) 10 httpd processes that are handling my external traffic on port 80 and another set of (say) 10 httpd processes that are handling my internal traffic on port 8080?

(Or do I need to run two instances of apache to achieve this?)

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

You can listen on both ports with one instance, but you don't get to determine the instances assigned to each port.  You would have to run two instances, each with their own configuration, to get that level of control.